# Using `search=term1,term2` to match multiple tags for the same object using DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm uplifting an old Django 1.11 codebase to recent versions of Django and Django Rest Framework, but I've run into a hard wall around how the `?search=...` filter works when using multiple terms in recent versions of Django Rest Framework.

Up until DRF version 3.6.3 it was possible to do a `?search=term1,term2` endpoint request and have DRF return objects with many-to-many relations in which both search terms matched the same field name, e.g if the model had a many-to-many field called `tags` relating to some model `Tag`, then an object with tags `cake` and `baker` could be found by DRF by asking for `?search=cake,baker`.

In the codebase I'm uplifting, the (reduced) code for this looks like:

```py
class TagQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def public(self):
        return self

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    objects = TagQuerySet.as_manager()
    def _get_entry_count(self):
        return self.entries.count()
    entry_count = property(_get_entry_count)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name',]

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=600, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='entries', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "entries"
        ordering = ['-id']

class EntryCustomFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    tag = django_filters.CharFilter(name='tags__name', lookup_expr='iexact', )
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = [ 'tags', ]

class EntriesListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    - `?search=` - Searches title, description, and tags
    - `&format=json` - return results in JSON rather than HTML format
    """
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter, )
    filter_class = EntryCustomFilter
    search_fields = ('title', 'description', 'tags__name', )
    parser_classes = ( JSONParser, )
```

However, this kind of behaviour for `search` got inadvertently [changed in 3.6.4](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/7094), so that DRF now instead only matches if a *single relation* found through a many-to-many field matches all terms. So, an Entry with a `tags` field that has relations to `Tag(name="cake")` and `Tag(name="baker")` no longer matches, as there is no single Tag that matches both terms, but an Entry with `Tag(name="baker of cake")` and `Tag(name="teller of tales")` *does* match, as there is a single relation that matches both terms.

There is (at least at the time of writing) no documentation that I can find that explains how to achieve this older behaviour for the generic `search` filter, nor can I find any previously asked questions here on Stackoverflow about making DRF work like this again (or even "at all"). There are some questions around specific field-named filters, but none for `search=`.

So: what changes can I make here so that `?search=...` keeps working as before, while using a DRF version 3.6.4+? I.e. how does one make the `?search=term1,term2` filter find models in which many-to-many fields have *separate* relations that match one or more of the specified terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior in DRF, introduced in order to optimize the M2M search/filter, as of [3.6.4](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#364). The reason this was introduced was to prevent a combinatorial explosion when using more than one term (See ["SearchFilter time grows exponentially by # of search terms"](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4655) and its associated PR ["Fix SearchFilter to-many behavior/performance "](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5264) for more details).

In order to perform the same kind of matching as in 3.6.3 and below, you need to create a custom search filter class by extending `filters.SearchFilter`, and add a custom implementaiton for the `filter_queryset` definition (the original definition can be found [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.6.3/rest_framework/filters.py#L129-L155) for DRF v3.6.3).

```python
from rest_framework import filters
import operator
from functools import reduce
from django.db import models
from rest_framework.compat import distinct


class CustomSearchFilter(filters.SearchFilter):

    def required_m2m_optimization(self, view):
        return getattr(view, 'use_m2m_optimization', True)

    def get_search_fields(self, view, request):
        # For DRF versions >=3.9.2 remove this method,
        # as it already has get_search_fields built in.
        return getattr(view, 'search_fields', None)

    def chained_queryset_filter(self, queryset, search_terms, orm_lookups):
        for search_term in search_terms:
            queries = [
                models.Q(**{orm_lookup: search_term})
                for orm_lookup in orm_lookups
            ]
            queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(operator.or_, queries))
        return queryset

    def optimized_queryset_filter(self, queryset, search_terms, orm_lookups):
        conditions = []
        for search_term in search_terms:
            queries = [
                models.Q(**{orm_lookup: search_term})
                for orm_lookup in orm_lookups
            ]
            conditions.append(reduce(operator.or_, queries))

        return queryset.filter(reduce(operator.and_, conditions))

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        search_fields = self.get_search_fields(view, request)
        search_terms = self.get_search_terms(request)

        if not search_fields or not search_terms:
            return queryset

        orm_lookups = [
            self.construct_search(str(search_field))
            for search_field in search_fields
        ]

        base = queryset
        if self.required_m2m_optimization(view):
            queryset = self.optimized_queryset_filter(queryset, search_terms, orm_lookups)
        else:
            queryset = self.chained_queryset_filter(queryset, search_terms, orm_lookups)

        if self.must_call_distinct(queryset, search_fields):
            # Filtering against a many-to-many field requires us to
            # call queryset.distinct() in order to avoid duplicate items
            # in the resulting queryset.
            # We try to avoid this if possible, for performance reasons.
            queryset = distinct(queryset, base)
        return queryset
```

Then, replace the `filters.Searchfilter` in your `filter_backends` with this custom class:

```python
class EntriesListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    filter_backends = (
        filters.DjangoFilterBackend,
        CustomSearchFilter,
        ...
    )
    use_m2m_optimization = False  # this attribute control the search results
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit!!. I have introduced a new method `get_optimization_operator()` which will help us to control the search behavior. What you have to do is set `use_m2m_optimization` attribute on the view which accept the boolean value

Comment: I purposefully removed it in favor of `get_search_fields()` method

Comment: I prefer to keep the `get_search_fields()` method since the DRF community introduced the same in DRF==3.9.2. Anyway I put a comment regarding the same in the code snippet

Comment: I have made a few changes to the answer :)

Comment: Awesome! Tests pass as before now with m2m optimization set to `False`. This is perfect, thank you so much for taking the time.